# Can death occur without Allah's will.?

Tags: death

This could be a strange question. I know Allah is the almighty who written our death day when we born. But i saw some accidents and some strange death's. Does saitan have a power of causing death to us? Or can death occur without Allah's will. ? Some one please answer this question. ? Thanks in Advance. . Any hadith reference would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually no matter how we die, it Does happens with the WILL of Allah. And Yes, Satan (Jinn) can cause harm to us (but the harm will only be limited to extent, which Allah has allowed. If our time has come for death and Jinn are also harming us, so we can die too at that time, when some jinn is trying to kill us. But that will only happen if Allah wished, no otherwise.

There is simple rule in islam, whatever happens, it happens with the Will of Allah Almighty